# qt4 QtConcurrent performance issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, memory, cpu

I'm trying to split function calls in 4 different Threads using QtConcurrent. A simplified version of my code:

```
void Myclass someFunction(){

int ct=0;
for ( int i = -500000; i < 500000; i+=4)
      if(multiThreadingEnabled){
            QtConcurrent::run(this,&Myclass::heavyCalc, i, ct);
            QtConcurrent::run(this,&Myclass::heavyCalc, i+1, ct+1);
            QtConcurrent::run(this,&Myclass::heavyCalc, i+2, ct+2);
            QtConcurrent::run(this,&Myclass::heavyCalc, i+3, ct+3);
            }
            else {...}
            ct+=4;
....
}

void Mygraph::heavyCalc(int,int){
....
      resArr[ct][0]=i;
      resArr[ct][1]=operation(i);
....
}
```

The idea is to have 4 Threads using all 4 cores (works). Without threading, only 1 core is used. I expected 4x faster calculations, but it's rather +10-20%...

1. Are multiple calls to QtConcurrent inefficient / is there a better way?
2. Is the calculation slowed down by memory (the result is stored in a very large array) ?
3. Is it generally wrong to expect 4x faster calculations when using 4 cores instead of one?

Comment: When creating new threads there is some overhead (for allocating and launching - for threads, for adding QFutureWatcher into queue - for QtConcurrent), also there is overhead while threads work. In your code you create 250000 tasks, this number seems to be too large... (as for me, of course)

Comment: You can consider use [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP)

Comment: If `somefunction` is something called repeatedly, may be helpful to generate a threadpool on construction of `Mygraph` and farm out the `heavyCalc` there